# ScrollPane adding to grid layout

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jscrollpane, windowbuilder

in my code I am calling a few items(my buttons with their names leading to different project. The names and everything are taken from a database)
I want a J ScrollPane to surround my buttons, what can I do? I just want the buttons to be called inside the scroll pane. Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class AdminClass implements ActionListener  {

ProjectButton[] buttons = new ProjectButton[35];

//Creating data field for unique Ids in the form of array list
ArrayList<Integer> uniqueIDList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String[] projectNames;
int[] uniqueIds;

Connection conn1 = null;
Statement stmt1 = null;

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Admin Panel");
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add New Project");

public AdminClass() {

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));

    panel.add(new JLabel("Welcome to Admin Panel"));

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    panel.add(new JLabel("Existing Projects"));

    conn1 = sqliteConnection.dbConnector();

    try{
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          conn1.setAutoCommit(false);
          stmt1 = conn1.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Project;" );

          List<String> projectNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

          while ( rs1.next() ){
              int id = rs1.getInt("uniqueid");
              String projectName = rs1.getString("name");

              projectNameList.add(projectName);
              uniqueIDList.add(id);
          }

          // Converting array list to array
          projectNames = new String[projectNameList.size()];
          projectNameList.toArray(projectNames);

          uniqueIds = convertIntegers(uniqueIDList);


          rs1.close();
          stmt1.close();
          conn1.close();
    }
    catch ( Exception e1 ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);    
    }

    // Adding buttons to the project
    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < projectNames.length; i++){
            buttons[i] = new ProjectButton(projectNames[i]);
            buttons[i].setId(uniqueIds[i]);

            panel.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e2){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
    }

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j ++){
        if (e.getSource() == buttons[j]){
            AdminStatus sc = new AdminStatus(buttons[j].getId());
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btnNewButton){

        frame.dispose();
        WindowProjectAdmin wpa = new WindowProjectAdmin();

    }

}

//Method to convert integar array list to integar array
public int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

This may seem very normal but it's really not, for some reason they are not visible or are not called inside a scroller. Please edit my code maybe?

Comment: `frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));`?

Comment: This is what I am trying to say, it's not as simple as it seems. You would know if you run the code. I just want the button part to be inside J Scroll Pane.

Comment: `You would know if you run the code` We can't, that's why we usually ask for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So?  Move the buttons to a separate `JPanel` add both panels to the frame, the first to the `BorderLayout.NORTH` and the second, wrapped in a `JScrollPane` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position...And my first suggestion "will" work, but since you haven't clarified "how" you want to the UI to look, we can only guess at it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by adding the buttons to their own container, this way you can control the layout of the buttons separately from the rest of the UI

```
    JPanel panelFullOfButtons = new JPanel();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectNames.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new ProjectButton(projectNames[i]);
            buttons[i].setId(uniqueIds[i]);

            panelFullOfButtons.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
    }
```

Then add the "main" panel to the `NORTH` position of the frame and the "buttons" panel to the `CENTER`

```
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(panelFullOfButtons), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Mind you, in this case, I'd be very tempted to use something like a `JList` instead.  See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

> I have done the same, can you tell me what's wrong?

```
// Problem #1...
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
pane.add(buttonPanel);

//...
// Problem #2...
panel.add(pane);
frame.add(panel);
```

These are competing with each other, moving the content around and overlapping with existing content...

[image: List of buttons]

```
public AdminClass() {

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    panel.add(new JLabel("Welcome to Admin Panel"));

    btnNewButton.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(btnNewButton);

    panel.add(new JLabel("Existing Projects"));

    List<String> projectNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
        projectNameList.add("Project " + index);
    }
    projectNames = projectNameList.toArray(new String[0]);

    // Adding buttons to the project
    buttons = new JButton[projectNameList.size()];
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < projectNames.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(projectNames[i]);

            btnPnl1.add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
    }

    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(btnPnl1), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

}
```

In this case I'd prefer to use either a `JList` to show the projects or a [`WrapLayout`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) for laying out the buttons

Comment: http://imgur.com/jj9BOQ0,kBfJ6Dw

I have done the same, can you tell me what's wrong? Still not working.
Check the layout? There's jut the scroll pane and no buttons inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Its useless to create a `GridLayout` like this: `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));`. If you declare the rows as a non zero value, the column count will be ignored. When you declare the maximum number of rows as ten, you force the eleventh component to be added in a second column (then a third, a forth and so on). Use `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));` instead to force the only one column and `frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));` to create the `ScrollPane`.

But note that `GridLayout` will try to shrink your components the maximum as possible to fit the container size before scrolling is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want the button part to be inside J Scroll Pane

If you just want the JButton's (those added within the loop):

1. Create a new `JPanel` that you add the buttons to
2. Add (1) to a `JScrollPane`
3. Add (2) to `panel`

For example:

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
for (int i = 0; i < projectNames.length; i++){
    buttons[i] = new ProjectButton(projectNames[i]);
    buttons[i].setId(uniqueIds[i]);
    panel.add(buttons[i]);
    buttonPanel[i].addActionListener(this);
}
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(buttonPanel);
panel.add(scroller);
```

You might also consider using a different Component that doesn't require a `JScrollPane`, of course depending upon your needs - for instance a [JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Comment: Did not work out brother, the buttons still don't spawn. Could you edit my code?

Comment: @SkibRs How did it "not work out"?  What does "buttons still don't spawn" mean?